# Resolving Entity Framework's AccountController with Simple Injector and Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, simple-injector

There is an issue of AccountController instantiation due to the dependencies of ApplicationUserManager, UserStore in asp .net Web api. I am able to succesfully register all other dependencies for simple injector DI.

I have searched a number of places to inject the right instances/types but could not conclusively do it properly yet.

Is there a way for me to ignore the default RegisterWebApiControllers given by simple injector so that I can avoid instantiating the AccountController via simple injector? Of is it impractical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the `AccountController`'s default constructor. It is as simple as that.

Another option is to override the `AccountController` registration as follows:

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config);

container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;

container.Register<AccountController>(() => new AccountController());

container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = false;
```

Here are some interesting reads when using Identity with Simple Injector:

- https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/564822
- https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/578859
- https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/37
- https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/93

Comment: Thanks. I think I am getting close, but you have answered my original question.